# how to get this layout in wordpress website. Is there any plugin to get this?

Tags: wordpress

[image: Screenshot here]

I've found that grid clickable layout on hackhands.com and I want to integrate on my website.

source: https://hackhands.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Visual Slide Box Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-visual-slidebox-builder/) plugin for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks bro for ur kind help.